# There is no metric d,so that (Q,d) is a connected space

Tags: general-topology

Can anyone prove this?

**There is no metric d,so that (Q,d) is a connected space**

Q are rationals.

Comment: Fix $a$ and consider $f(x) = d(x,a)$.

Comment: I don't see a contradiction? :/ U suppose that (Q,d) is connected, then function f would be continuous,surjection,so R+ would be connected?

Comment: Not necessarily a surjection. Think about cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

Pick any point $x$. If for any $r\in\mathbb R_+$, the circle $\{y\mid d(x,y)=r\}$ is empty, then
$$\{y\mid d(x,y)<r\}=\{y\mid d(x,y)\le r\},$$
so it must be clopen.

Assuming a connected space has at least $2$ points, all sufficiently small $r$ must find a point on the corresponding circle, proving there are uncountably (even $\frak c$) many.